# How to populate nested model in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have dataSubmitted model:

```
module.exports = (mongoose, mongoosePaginate) => {
  const schema = mongoose.Schema({
    user: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'User'
    },
    company: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'User'
    },
  }, {
    timestamps: true
  })

  schema.plugin(mongoosePaginate)

  const dataSubmitted = mongoose.model('dataSubmitted', schema)

  return dataSubmitted
}
```

And i have the other model is called "profile" for user profile. I use user._id to releation with "profile" model.

My profile model:

```
module.exports = (mongoose, mongoosePaginate) => {
  const schema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    user: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'User'
    },
  }, {
    timestamps: true
  })

  schema.plugin(mongoosePaginate)

  const profile = mongoose.model('profile', schema)

  return profile
}
```

The result json from select dataSubmitted, is like this:

```
totalItems": 90,
    "data": [
        {
            "_id": "63546cb05bfb8607c005da6a",
            "user": "6353a1aebaf28d7aa066a963",
            "company": "6022487bbe148f3a9b132122",
            "createdAt": "2022-10-22T22:20:32.296Z",
            "updatedAt": "2022-10-25T07:09:52.363Z",
            "__v": 0
        },
     ]
```

My question is how can i populate the user id with "profile" model?

My current code:

```
const options = {
    populate: [
      {
        path: 'user',
        populate: {
          path: 'user',
          model: 'profile'
        }
      }
    ],
    sort: ({ createdAt: -1 })
  }
```

but its return "user": null if i add nested populate like that.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to reference the `profile` model from the `dataSubmitted` you should change your schema declaration to:

```
const dataSubmittedSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    profile: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'profile',
    },
    company: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'User',
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);
```

Then, you should be able to `populate` with:

```
dataSubmitted.find({}).populate({
    path: 'profile',
    populate: {
        path: 'user'
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, so its not possible to populate through "user" referenced?

Comment: If you need to populate the user associated to a profile you need to store the profile reference in the `dataSubmitted` schema